# Prove that $\exists \, x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)$ does not equal $f(y)$ for every rational number $y.$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f:\mathbb R \longrightarrow \mathbb R$ be a non-constant continuous function. Prove that there is an $x \in \mathbb R$ such that $f(x)$ does not equal $f(y)$ for every rational number $y.$

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Hint: $f(\mathbb{Q})$ is countable. Is $f(\mathbb{R})$ countable?

Comment: What can you say about $f({{R}})$ and $f({Q})$ ?

Comment: It might be interesting for you to try to think of a non-example when the hypothesis of continuity is removed.

Comment: Since Q is countable then f(Q) is countable. Since R is not countable then f(R) is not countable. So we can find an x in R such that it is not in Q. Thus f(x) is not equal to f(y) for every rational number y????

Comment: "Since R is not countable then f(R) is not countable" How come?

Comment: Isn't it because the function is not constant?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$f(\mathbb Q)$ is at most countable and the image of an interval is an interval not equal to a single point as $f$ is supposed to be non constant.